# API Design - Why BorderBrush has no effect on CheckBox?

Tags: wpf, uwp, api-design

In **UWP**, the `BorderBrush` has no effect on the `CheckBox`. The `BorderThickness` does have an effect, you can see there's like a transparent border around the control:

```
    <CheckBox BorderBrush="Red"
              BorderThickness="10"
              Background="Aqua"
              Content="CheckBox" />
    <RadioButton BorderBrush="Red"
                 BorderThickness="10"
                 Background="Aqua"
                 Content="RadioButton" />
```

[image]

The `RadioButton` works differently, it does use the brush.

**I'm NOT looking to understand how to make the CheckBox use the border brush, I already know that.**

What I'm looking for is to understand WHY did the UWP team decide to make it work like that? Is it just a bug or a slip from their side? I find it hard to believe it.

What's interesting is that in **WPF**, the border works differently for both the `CheckBox` and `RadioButton`:

[image]

I'm also curious to know why the **WPF** team made the decision to have the `BorderThickness` and `BorderBrush` work differently on CheckBox and RadioButton than for other controls which show border around the whole control. Button is the closest example. Is it maybe because they didn't want to add more specialized properties to customize the actual check/radio? If that's the case, didn't they lose the option to have a border around the whole control?

Comment: You can edit default template of those controls..

Comment: I can, that's not the question. if you read carefully, I mentioned I am not looking for an answer to that. I am only looking to understand why is it has this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Hex Code for color makes the trick

```
<CheckBox BorderBrush=" #000000"  Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="10" Background="Aqua" Content="CheckBox" />
```

Else you could use color converter and call it on the control

Comment: Thanks but I was not looking for how to do it, I mentioned this in the description

Answer (score 0):

For explaining this behaviour, you need to check [`CheckBox` styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299114.aspx). As you see `CheckBox` has some status in the `VisualStateGroups`. you just modify   `BorderBrush` property but you have not modify the following `StaticResource` that used for different `VisualState`.

```
<StaticResource x:Key="CheckBoxBorderBrushUnchecked" ResourceKey="SystemControlTransparentBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="CheckBoxBorderBrushUncheckedPointerOver" ResourceKey="SystemControlTransparentBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="CheckBoxBorderBrushUncheckedPressed" ResourceKey="SystemControlTransparentBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="CheckBoxBorderBrushUncheckedDisabled" ResourceKey="SystemControlTransparentBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="CheckBoxBorderBrushChecked" ResourceKey="SystemControlTransparentBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="CheckBoxBorderBrushCheckedPointerOver" ResourceKey="SystemControlTransparentBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="CheckBoxBorderBrushCheckedPressed" ResourceKey="SystemControlTransparentBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="CheckBoxBorderBrushCheckedDisabled" ResourceKey="SystemControlTransparentBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="CheckBoxBorderBrushIndeterminate" ResourceKey="SystemControlTransparentBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="CheckBoxBorderBrushIndeterminatePointerOver" ResourceKey="SystemControlTransparentBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="CheckBoxBorderBrushIndeterminatePressed" ResourceKey="SystemControlTransparentBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="CheckBoxBorderBrushIndeterminateDisabled" ResourceKey="SystemControlTransparentBrush" />
```

If you want modify border color completely, you need to modify the above `StaticResource`, for example.

**Method 1**

Make a new `SolidColorBrush` with `CheckBoxBorderBrushxxxxx` key to cover the default one.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBoxBorderBrushUnchecked" Color="Red"/>
```

**Method 2**

Use the the default `StaticResource`, but modify `ResourceKey` to another one.

```
<StaticResource x:Key="CheckBoxBorderBrushUnchecked" ResourceKey="SystemChromeBlackLowColor" />
```

[image]

**Update**

This is latest CheckBox full [xaml template](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/MoveTextTest/blob/master/MoveTextTest/MainPage.xaml#L104)

Comment: Thanks but I can't see for example CheckBoxBorderBrushUnchecked anywhere on the page you mentioned  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299114.aspx  The setter is hardcoded to `Transparent`: `<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />`

Comment: Sorry, that version is expire in, For latest one, you could right click Checkbox and Edit Template - > Edit copy in the xaml designer.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I still don't see why UWP team decided to make CheckBox use the value of BorderBrush different than RadioButton and other controls.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, if you have any confuse or requirement  about control design, please feel free post it on [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?query=pin%20secondary%20tile%20without%20user%20consent). And if you think this answer is helpful please consider accept it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't answer my question. I appreciate your help. I still don't understand why CheckBox uses BorderBrush different than RadioButton.

Comment: You could check `RadioButton`'s style and it is simple relatively, and the `Normal` state is empty, that is why it could display the border in default state. They are different controls, they can't require the same design ideas.